# Loop to apply command to 300 files in a directory and rename the output including the original input file name plus new text

Tags: rename, function, for

I have a code that is svr_vars. I have a directory with 300 different files. I want to loop it and to run the code on each file in the directory. The svr_vars code outputs a generic filename of svr_vars.txt. Therefore, every time the code is run, it overwrites the svr_vars.txt filename. So, it needs to be renamed after every run of the code.

1995051200_72259.txt <= what one file in the directory looks like

I want the output to be renamed from svr_vars.txt to svr.1995051200_72259.txt

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, you basically do

```
svr_vars 1995051200_72259.txt
```

and the program generates output called `svr_vars.txt` and you want this renamed to `svr.1995051200_72259.txt`

Assuming that all the 300 files begin with a number and end in `.txt` then you can do a loop similar to

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in [1-9]*.txt
do
  svr_vars "$file"
  mv svr_vars.txt "svr.$file"
done
```

We can add some sanity checks to this loop to cause it to abort if things don't work properly.  eg

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in [1-9]*.txt
do
  if [ -e "svr.$file" ]
  then
    echo "$file already processed.  skipping"
  else
    svr_vars "$file"
    if [ ! -e svr_vars.txt ]
    then
      echo "Failed to create results for $file"
    else
      mv svr_vars.txt "svr.$file"
    fi
  fi
done
```